# How to flip the screen without clicking the item in the listView

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have two views in my `ViewFlipper`. One of views contains a `ListView` with an `OnClickListener`. The `ViewFlipper` works fine with blank views.

However, when I put on the `ListView` and try to flip the current view into the next view, the item on the list view is clicked which I don't want during flipping.

Is there any function I can use to disable the interruption of the child view?

Comment: on which event u have try to flip ur view

Comment: if don't do anything on listview item click, better you disable the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Solutions here in this SO posts [ViewFlipper not flipping with child listview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924817/582571) & [Listview Swipe inside viewflipper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927084/582571)

Comment: first see the title of que and than give an answer

Comment: Thanks@Android Coader, but when i want to swipe the view it also become a click action

Comment: @Ricky did you find ur solution ?