# ViewFlipper and onTouchListener in listView's header

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

In my application, I have a listView. I have a ViewFlipper which is the header of the ListView.

I want the ViewFlipper to switch views when the user touch it and slide. Also, the items of the ViewFlipper are clickable.
My problem is my ListView is also scrollable, but vertically, and clickable.

Here is a schema :

[image]

First, I tried to use an OnTouchEvent. It didn't work because the method is called even if the user touch the screen OUT of the ViewFlipper.

Now, if I use an OuTouchListener, I can't intercept the user's gesture and I can't figure it out.

Here is a sample of the XML code for the header of the listView:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipune"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="3" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/itemviewflipper1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/stritemviewflipper" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titreviewflipper1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemviewflipper1"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/itemviewflipper2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/stritemviewflipper" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titreviewflipper2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemviewflipper2"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

        [...]

</ViewFlipper>
```

And I defined the OnTouchListener in the activity :

```
viewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchevent) {
                switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    oldTouchValue = touchevent.getX();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {           

                    float currentX = touchevent.getX();
                    if (touchevent.getY() < metrics.heightPixels / 3) {
                        if (!viewFlipper.isPressed() && oldTouchValue == currentX) {
                            openDescriptionArticle(index);
                        } else {
                            if (oldTouchValue < currentX) {
                                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationHelper
                                        .inFromLeftAnimation());
                                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationHelper
                                        .outToRightAnimation());
                                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                                if (index > 0) {
                                    index--;
                                } else {
                                    index= 4;
                                }
                            }
                            if (oldTouchValue > currentX) {
                                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationHelper
                                        .inFromRightAnimation());
                                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationHelper
                                        .outToLeftAnimation());
                                viewFlipper.showNext();
                                if (index < 4) {
                                    index++;
                                } else {
                                    index = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: it is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish based on what you've written here.

Comment: check the answer's link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11271615/582571

Comment: I checked the links but I think it does not answer to my problem. Indeed, I can scroll my listView and slide my ViewFlipper, but when I scroll my ListView, the ViewFlipper shows the next or previous items AND the ListView scrolls. Both actions work but I want only one of them (when I scroll the ListView OUT of the ViewFlipper, the ViewFlipper shouldn't move and when I slide the ViewFlipper, the ListView shouldn't move either).

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this? In the same boat now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is a `HorizontalPager` inside `ListView` header. ListView grabs touch event and pager freezes.
I've solved the problem by implementing custom `ListView` with `scrollingEnabled` option.

```
public class StoppableListView extends ListView {
    public boolean scrollingEnabled = true;
    YourActivity parent;

    public StoppableListView(Context context) { super(context); parent = (CalendarActivity)context; }
    public StoppableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); parent = (CalendarActivity)context; }
    public StoppableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { super(context,attrs); parent = (CalendarActivity)context; }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (scrollingEnabled) return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        // dispatch touch event to your view
        else return parent.yourView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

When pager is active I set `listView.scrollingEnabled = false` and event is properly dispatched to pager.