# How to Swipe ListView row in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, listview, gesture, viewflipper

I'm trying to  swipe left and right on a `ListView` in `ViewFlipper` which also changes view from left to right

I have two gesture classes , one for `ViewFlipper` and other for `ListView`.

My problem is when I try to apply `SimpleOnGestureListener` `ListView` its `Motionevent` e1 is always null

Is there any way to apply `gestureListner` on `ListView` in `ViewFlpper`.

Comment: May be this answer could help you out:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927084/listview-swipe-inside-viewflipper

Comment: i want to swipe left to right on Listview in View flipper thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using ViewFlipper. You can use ViewPager in android support library.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)